# Opening, editing and saving a csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv called pairList which looks like:

```
0    BBG.XNGS.AAPL.S  BBG.XNGS.BRCM.S  0
1    BBG.XNGS.AAPL.S  BBG.XNGS.MSFT.S  0
2    BBG.XNGS.AAPL.S  BBG.XNGS.AMAT.S  0
3    BBG.XNGS.AAPL.S  BBG.XNGS.QCOM.S  0
4    BBG.XNGS.AMGN.S   BBG.XNYS.MWW.S  0
5    BBG.XNGS.BRCM.S  BBG.XNGS.MSFT.S  0
6    BBG.XNGS.BRCM.S  BBG.XNGS.AMAT.S  0
7    BBG.XNGS.BRCM.S  BBG.XNGS.QCOM.S  0
8    BBG.XNGS.MSFT.S  BBG.XNGS.AMAT.S  0
9    BBG.XNGS.MSFT.S  BBG.XNGS.QCOM.S  0
10   BBG.XNGS.AMAT.S  BBG.XNGS.QCOM.S  0
11  BBG.XNGS.CMCSA.S  BBG.XNGS.CSCO.S  0
12  BBG.XNGS.CMCSA.S  BBG.XNGS.SYMC.S  0
13   BBG.XNGS.CSCO.S  BBG.XNGS.SYMC.S  0
```

I am trying to open the csv, look down each row until I find the first row where the 4 column is equal to 0 (in this case its the first row but it this would change).  Copy the data for this row to 3 variables

```
stock1ID
stock2ID 
status
```

Then update the status (the value in column 4 for the seelcted row) and then save the dataframe back to the csv.  So the csv would (in this example) end up looking like:

```
0    BBG.XNGS.AAPL.S  BBG.XNGS.BRCM.S  1
1    BBG.XNGS.AAPL.S  BBG.XNGS.MSFT.S  0
2    BBG.XNGS.AAPL.S  BBG.XNGS.AMAT.S  0
3    BBG.XNGS.AAPL.S  BBG.XNGS.QCOM.S  0
4    BBG.XNGS.AMGN.S   BBG.XNYS.MWW.S  0
5    BBG.XNGS.BRCM.S  BBG.XNGS.MSFT.S  0
6    BBG.XNGS.BRCM.S  BBG.XNGS.AMAT.S  0
7    BBG.XNGS.BRCM.S  BBG.XNGS.QCOM.S  0
8    BBG.XNGS.MSFT.S  BBG.XNGS.AMAT.S  0
9    BBG.XNGS.MSFT.S  BBG.XNGS.QCOM.S  0
10   BBG.XNGS.AMAT.S  BBG.XNGS.QCOM.S  0
11  BBG.XNGS.CMCSA.S  BBG.XNGS.CSCO.S  0
12  BBG.XNGS.CMCSA.S  BBG.XNGS.SYMC.S  0
13   BBG.XNGS.CSCO.S  BBG.XNGS.SYMC.S  0
```

I can open the csv and select the data asigning it to the 3 variables.  I can't save the updated csv.  I end up with a csv that looks like:

```
    0    BBG.XNGS.AAPL.S  BBG.XNGS.BRCM.S  0  1
    1    BBG.XNGS.AAPL.S  BBG.XNGS.MSFT.S  0  1
    2    BBG.XNGS.AAPL.S  BBG.XNGS.AMAT.S  0  1
    3    BBG.XNGS.AAPL.S  BBG.XNGS.QCOM.S  0  1
    4    BBG.XNGS.AMGN.S   BBG.XNYS.MWW.S  0  1
    5    BBG.XNGS.BRCM.S  BBG.XNGS.MSFT.S  0  1
    6    BBG.XNGS.BRCM.S  BBG.XNGS.AMAT.S  0  1
    7    BBG.XNGS.BRCM.S  BBG.XNGS.QCOM.S  0  1
    8    BBG.XNGS.MSFT.S  BBG.XNGS.AMAT.S  0  1
    9    BBG.XNGS.MSFT.S  BBG.XNGS.QCOM.S  0  1
    10   BBG.XNGS.AMAT.S  BBG.XNGS.QCOM.S  0  1
    11  BBG.XNGS.CMCSA.S  BBG.XNGS.CSCO.S  0  1
    12  BBG.XNGS.CMCSA.S  BBG.XNGS.SYMC.S  0  1
    13   BBG.XNGS.CSCO.S  BBG.XNGS.SYMC.S  0  1
```

The csv has an extra 4th column of 1's when all I want is that the row that has been select should have a 1 in the 3rd column only.

Please see below for the code that I have so far written:

```
def getPairID(TimeseriesDataPath):


#status = 0 - pair not processed
#status = 1 - pair being processed
#status = 2 - pair finined being processed
pattern = 'PairsToTestList'+'.csv'
pairToTest = 0
with open(TimeseriesDataPath+pattern,'rt') as f:
    pairList = pd.read_csv(f,engine='c',header=None,index_col=0, parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
    for i, row in pairList.iterrows():
        if i != 'unique_id':
            stock1ID = row[1]
            stock2ID = row[2]
            status = row[3]

            if status == 0 :
                print('stock1ID ',stock1ID,'stock2ID ',stock2ID,'status ',status)

                pairToTest = 1     
                pairList[row[2]] = 1


                path = os.path.join(TimeseriesDataPath,pattern)
                pairList.to_csv(path,header=False)
                break

    return stock1ID,stock2ID,pairToTest
```

Comment: Try: `pairList.to_csv(os.path.join(TimeseriesDataPath,pattern),header=False)`

Comment: Thanks bernie, using ,hea‌​der=False i get an SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Updated to include the iteration I think you're looking for.

I've also updated it using `.iloc` to find the integer position of the next line instead of using the index.

```
f = 'C:/Users/yourname/Desktop/test.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(f, header = None)

i = 0
while i <= df.index.max():
    subset = df.loc[df[2] == 0].head(1)

    if subset[0].count() == 0:
        stock1ID, stock2ID, status = None, None, None

    else:
        stock1ID, stock2ID, status = subset[0].iloc[0], subset[1].iloc[0], subset[2].iloc[0]
        print '{}, {}, {}'.format(stock1ID, stock2ID, status)
        df.loc[df.index == subset.index[0], 2] = 1

    i += 1

df.to_csv('C:/Users/Pete/Desktop/test2.csv', header = None)
```

Comment: Thanks pshep123, I tried to implement your solution but i get a IndexError: index out of bounds exception with stock1ID, stock2ID, status = subset[0][0], subset[1][0], subset[2][0]   any thoughts

Comment: If that's the case, none of the values in the far right columns were `0`.  I'll update the code to test for that.

Comment: Thanks,every iteration it adds a index column at the front of the csv (0,1,2,3,4,...) so it will only work for one iteration with subset = df.loc[df[2] == 0].head(1)

Comment: Updated with what I think you're looking for. I could put it in a function and return the variables, but that kills the loop.

Comment: Stacey, if this is at least helpful, an up vote would be appreciated. Understandable if it's not _the_ answer.